# Bad spacing around $\in$ symbol before math calligraphhic letter

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm using a math calligraphic font for some set U, and when I tried to state that X is an element of U `$X\in\mathcal{U}$`, I obtained a horrible result. Below is the code, with some other examples for comparison.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an nonprincipal ultrafilter. If
$X\in\mathcal{U}$, then $X$ is infinite.

\Huge

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
$X\in\mathcal{U}$ &    \verb#$X\in\mathcal{U}$#  \\
$X\in U$ &    \verb#$X\in U$#  \\
$X + \mathcal{U}$ &   \verb#$X + \mathcal{U}$# \\
$X + U$ &   \verb#$X + U$#
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of X \in \mathcal{U}]

So, there is too much space between `X` and `\in` and/or too little before `\mathcal{U}`. If you compare with the example of math italic U, there is a bit more of space *after* `\in` (and looks better).

Putting `X` or `\mathcal{U}$` between braces doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The math italic U has sidebearings, whereas the calligraphic U hasn't them. If you deem the result is bad, type `$X\in\,\mathcal{U}$`

Comment: @egreg I didn't want to do it “by hand”, but if there is no other solution I'll do.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a font design decision; unless you choose another calligraphic font or prepare yourself a virtual font that adds sidebearings to the letters you need, there's not much to do. You may want to try `eucal` or `calrsfs`

Comment: Experiments have shown that \mathcal characters have sidebearrings, but they differ from regular italics and from each other.

Comment: @egreg `eucal` has the same “problem” and `calrsfs` is way too slanted. I found that `rsfso` works fine for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a demonstration of italic and mathcal fonts.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{mycount}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\parbox{25pt}{\baselineskip=0pt
\lineskip=0pt
\loop\stepcounter{mycount}
\fbox{$\color{red}\Alph{mycount}$}%
\fbox{$\color{red}\mathcal{\Alph{mycount}}$}
\ifnum\value{mycount}<26\relax\repeat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use also `\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}`

Comment: Useful, I was wondering how to do that.